# is there any impact if I give access of Apex and vf page access to any profile

Tags: apex, profile, permissions

if i give access to apex class which is not required for any profile ,is there any impact,

Requirement .i have to give some classes access to profile but i am thinking to give all classes access to that profile.is there any impact

Comment: I think that only you can know if there is any problem to give access to theses classes. The main problem I see is: if you have some web services classes and you don't want the user to be able to call these web services, you can't allowed him to execute methods in theses classes.

Comment: Before enabling apex permission for profiles have a look at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53803/when-to-add-apex-class-permissions-to-a-profile

Answer (score 2):

Apex code can be written to bypass record-level rules (create/read/update/delete records that the user cannot normally do) and to bypass field-level-security (view/modify fields on records that the user cannot normally do).

If you have page/classes which do this, you could accidentally be allowing your users to perform operations that would be impossible via their profile permissions alone.

It's more hassle for the administrator, but it is more secure to make users ask for permissions (e.g. you forgot to give them a class that you should have given them) than for forgiveness (e.g. someone fired up a VF page that was only meant for admins and deleted all of your data).