# User Automation and Future Method and Permissions Issue

Tags: apex, profile, user, future, ui

I am stumped on a problem and was hoping someone could spur some thought.

I have two users who have different profiles. The System Admin profile is able to get through a `Future Method` and a Webservice. The Analyst profile is not able to enter into the `Future Method`.

The System Admin is firing off the Future Method with a trigger.

The Analyst is firing off the Future Method with UI (a button on the Opportunity).

The Analyst is getting a permissions error:

> You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.

This obviously means to me there is a permissions issue with the profiles, but all objects and sharing rules have been granted. I have checked multiple times. Am I just blind and missing an permission setting on an object? Or is there something else I should be looking for?

I am getting very little information from the debug log. It just skips over the future method and has no error messages. The error is only displayed on the screen for the user.

Comment: Is this button calling an Apex Class? If so, you need to add the class to the profile.

Comment: Related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53803

Comment: thank you @sfdcfox the Apex Classes are included as well as the VFPs. Good suggestion though